# Css Transform Effect in MongoDB site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to css and learning different type of css styles. I want to learn how the effect used in official MongoDb website. The effect which tracks the mouse position and transforms the boxes. I know how to do the transform in css. But, how can it be done with the mouse position. Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/

Comment: The major property from css is used here is `transform: rotateY(0.01deg) rotateX(0.01deg);` try to debug more deeper into the inspect you will get to know more. Cheers!

Comment: This is done rather poorly, on my screen the transformed squares are not antialiased at all in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General overview of how to do it:

1. Register a [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event)-handler and track your mouse-screen location (see link)
2. translate mouse screenlocation, to mouse location relative to rectangle:

   - `e.target` in mousemove event gives you the rectangle (or some descendent which allows you to get to the rectangle.
   - given the target element get it's position (top + left using `getBoundingClientRect`) as well as width and height. These should be easy to lookup
3. Notice that the mouse at the center of the rectangle doesn't rotate the rectangle. Only when moving to the edges, the rotation starts to get going. This rotational rate-of-change seems to be linear. So:

   - determine the max rotation that seems nice to have in degrees. Simply test with different numbers in the chrome dev tools or similar: `transform: rotateY(0.01deg) rotateX(0.01deg);` Say you want to have a max rotation of 25 degrees.
   - say the rectangle is 100px in width. It's clear to see that each pixel movement from the center to the edge (50 px in total) adds 0.5 degree to the rotation due to the linear rate of change: 25 deg / 50px. So for example moving 20px to the left of the center translates to `rotateY(10deg);`. Moving 20px to the right results in the mirror rotation (`rotateY(-10deg);`). NOTE: the positive and negative may need to be flipped.
   - similarly, moving along the Y-axis changes the `rotateX-property`.
   - Once calculated, set the css-property and you're done

Answer (score 1):

I believe this must be done with Javascript. The general idea is when the mouse enter/move on the element, you compare it's coordinate with the position and width/height of the element to decide the rotation values. When the mouse leave the element, you reset the values of the rotation back to normal.

You can get the coordinate of the mouse from event by using:

```
const mouseX = event.clientX;     // Get the horizontal coordinate
const mouseY = event.clientY;     // Get the vertical coordinate
```

And the position of the element:

```
const eleLoc = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
```

From there you calculate the center and the width/height of the element:

```
const centerX = (eleLoc.right + eleLoc.left) / 2
const centerY = (eleLoc.bottom + eleLoc.top) / 2
const halfWidth = (eleLoc.right - eleLoc.left) / 2
const halfHeight = (eleLoc.bottom- eleLoc.top) / 2
```

Then you calculate the distance between the mouse and the center in percent. In the center, the distance is 0, at the border, it's 1 (or -1).

```
const percentX = (mouseX - centerX) / halfWidth
const percentY = (mouseY - centerY) / halfHeight
```

Now you only need to rotate X/Y based on the distance percent:

```
const degX = percentX * maxDegX
const defY = percentY * maxDegY
event.target.style.transform = `perspective(${yourPerspective}px) rotateX(${degX}deg) rotateY(${degY}deg)`
```

Remember to reset the transform when your mouse move out.

---

There are some libraries for this, ie: [tilt.js](https://github.com/gijsroge/tilt.js)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will use the tilt.js